# how to use python 3's pip?

Tags: python, python3, pip

I want to switch my project from python 2.7 to python 3.4 and I want to use python3's virtualenvwrapper and pip.

I have tried `sudo apt-get install python3-pip`, `easy_install3 pip` and `python3 get-pip.py` but when I perform pip -V i get

```
doc@ubuntu:~$ pip -V
pip 7.0.0 from /home/doc/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)
```

for each.

what can I do?

edit: I'm not asking about pyenv, I just want to use python3 and its pip as i did with python2

edit2: I got this error even if I've installed python3-pip

```
doc@ubuntu:~$ pip3 -V
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip3", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3020, in <module>
    working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 616, in _build_master
    return cls._build_from_requirements(__requires__)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 629, in _build_from_requirements
    dists = ws.resolve(reqs, Environment())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 807, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: pip==6.1.1
```

Answer (score 4):

Ubuntu has Python 2.7 set as default. So, running python or pip normally runs the 2.7 version.

If you want to run version 3 then you have to use the command python3 and pip3

```
pip3 -V

python3 -V
```

For the virtual envirmoment if found the command pyvenv-3.4

```
pyvenv-3.4 myenv_folder #Creates a python 3.4 virtual enviroment in the myenv_folder
cd myenv_folder
source bin/activate #Activates the virtual environment
```

Comment: btw, i get "pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: pip==6.1.1"